# Self-Signed Certificates and Urllib with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, self-signed

I have a self-signed certificate file, and I need to make requests to a REST endpoint that requires the certificate.  How do I pass this information using the standard python 2.7.x libraries?

Is there a way I can check if the current user has the self-signed certificate installed in the certificate store on Windows?  If so, can I grab the certificate?

How do you just use urllib/urllib2 to pass a self-signed certificate?

Thank you

Comment: Just use the requests library instead of the built in urllibx libraries.

Comment: Yes, reuqest is a good library, but I need to support both standard and request library.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Can I ask why you can't just use the external library?

Comment: It's a copy/security thing.  I'm just trying to play the hand I'm dealt.

Comment: Sorry company thing, not copy.

Comment: If the policy is that you cannot use an external library @josh1234, what about copying the necessary functionality to your own project? Just make sure that the requests library allows that (e.g., they may just ask that you indicate the writer of each of the functions you embed at the docstring of it inside your code: email the writer, explain your problem, and he may agree).